# How to route an url to local directory? (Description inside)

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing

I had a site in which all the images are inside a sub directory in my site. But I need to save those pictures in a specific directory and I need to show the in a client application which holds my page url.

for example: I had an url, http://foo.example.com/images/happy.jpg

the site is in c:/Example.

i'll store the images in c:/Images/categories/category1/happy.jpg

if my client request the above url, I need to redirect it to the image in the folder, where I kept all my images.

can somebody say is this possible? If possible, please suggest a way to accomplish this through url routing

Comment: Why not store them in a virtual directory and link to there???

Comment: @ShellNinja actually I don't know how to achieve this. That's y asked for suggestions. Thanks for the reply, If it can done by virtual directory can you say me how to achieve it with authorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to add a virtual directory to your IIS configuration for the folder where the images are held. Once the virtual directory is added you can reference the files via a URL to the virtual path. This is the best way in a production enviroment.

[Technet step by step guide to adding a virtual directory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771804%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

As for no authorization, you should select "Application User" (pass-through authentication). If you nest the new virtual directory inside the application's VD, you may need to add a web.config file to the virtual directory to override any authorization/deny rules in the root web.config file.

For local debugging, if the images are on your local PC, you can use a file:/// url replacing c:\ with file:/// and forward slashes instead of back slashes for the rest of the path. Don't forget to escape the slashes in the code behind by using "@".

Alternatively, a more involved solution would be configuring local IIS similar to above and using local IIS instead of the ASP.net runtime server which uses localhost:port using the link above and configuring your project to use IIS. If you are building this project over a long period of time local IIS makes the most sense. Short projects can be easily done without local IIS.

[How to configure a project to use Local IIS for debugging](http://codetunnel.com/blog/post/how-to-debug-your-aspnet-projects-running-under-iis)

Comment: This doesn't work. when the request is coming from the client to access the link, it doesn't refer the path.

Comment: In the example you gave:

New Virtual Directory - Name would be "Images"
Physical Path would be - c:/Images/categories/category1/